# youtube video issue, after downloaded using php script

Tags: php, download, youtube

After download video not playing, get error "This file ins't playable. That might be because the file type is unsupported, the file extension is incorrect, or the file is corrupted."

https://r1---sn-n4v7sne7.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?mm=31%2C26&mn=sn-n4v7sne7%2Csn-a5mlrn7r&id=o-AESqnRG-D_kBvnItpMhmc7wJvzd04UFgM2drxtqdRVlg&sparams=clen%2Cdur%2Cei%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cexpire&ip=52.8.2.36&key=yt6&mt=1525433022&gir=yes&mv=u&ms=au%2Conr&clen=1030808&ipbits=0&fexp=23724337&signature=5B6D288692FE64C9045316DB49F44ED7A9B2B125.79F5C487797F95E2D417806D179410FF55309C5F&ratebypass=yes&c=WEB&expire=1525455044&mime=video%2Fmp4&dur=23.080&itag=18&pl=23&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&lmt=1511505645615082&ei=ZETsWoCpIpDv_APaqpPYCg&fvip=1

```
        $vformat = 'video/mp4'; // The MIME type of the video. e.g. video/mp4, video/webm, etc.
        parse_str(file_get_contents('http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=T74O9LGSR-M', $video_data);
        $streams = $video_data['url_encoded_fmt_stream_map'];
        $streams = explode(',',$streams);
        foreach($streams as $stream){
        parse_str($stream,$data); //Now decode the stream
        if(stripos($data['type'],$vformat) !== false){
            $url = $data['url'].'&asv=2';
            $format = '.mp4';
            $filename = 'video1'.$format;

            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
            header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"");

            readfile($url);
            exit;
         }
```

Comment: `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` — that isn't a MIME type used by any video format.

Comment: Quentin, can you please help me to sort out issues ?